# AngularJS filter show only matched word as result, not entire string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to display only the matched word in ng-repeat with filters?

For example I have the following strings

```
[
{text: 'This is first text from the array.'},
{text: 'Text in this array is dummy and it makes no sense'}, 
{text: 'AngularJS is very old framework'}
]
```

If I search for characters  "fr", then I want in my list to display only ti elements: "from" from the first string and "framework" from the last string in the array. I don't need to display the entire string.

Result should be for example:

```
<li>from</li>
<li>framework</li>
```

In filter service, I tried to update the {text:} value to be equal to the match value, but it updates the original array of objects;

Here is my JSFiddle [Filter Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Octavianus/apwm0fxL/41/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not nice but you can try this, its almost giving what you want.
I would suggest you to render the search in other ng-repeat block that can be neat and efficient.

```
items.filter(list => {
        if (list.text.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)) {
          let catchPattern = new RegExp('(\\w*' + filterValue + '\\w*)', 'gi');
          let matches = list.text.toLowerCase().match(catchPattern)
          if (!matches)
            return items;

          filterdArray.push({
            'text': matches,
            'id': list.id
          })
        }

      });
```

Attached fiddle for the same:
[Find Word from the string](http://jsfiddle.net/6ezv9r4u/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. It has a downside because it throws the “Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached” But, I figured out how to get rig of this issue.

Comment: i was looking  around for some ways to end digest cycle, it would be good if you can let me know how did you achieve it?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Octavianus/37apq5sn/5/     Basically, you use a $watch to call the filter in js and need to remove the fitler in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your strings to arrays with individual words, which you can filter to find only the words in a string that match your filter string. Here is an example:

```
var text = value.text.split(' ');
var matchedWords = []
matchedWords = text.filter(res => res.indexOf(filterValue) > -1)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brmt0cLj/8/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It still updates the original list. But thanks.